# django:: invoking middleware in tests

Tags: django, testing, django-testing

I have a middleware function which defines `request.foo`. A function I want to test depends on foo being defined from the middleware. How do I test said function since the middleware isn't run during tests?

There really should be a function which takes in a request, runs the request through all the middleware in order, then spits out the final request (just as it would be when passed to a view). Does such a function exist?

I could manually call the middleware function, but that seems like a hack. What if the middleware under test depends on another middleware? I would run into "middleware hell".

### < example >

middleware function:

```
class FooMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        req.foo = True if req.session.get('foo') in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] else False
```

Here's the function I want to test:

```
def getBaz(request):
    if request.foo == True:
        return something()
    else:
        return somethingElse()
```

How do I test `getBaz`?

### < /example >

### < Possibility >

I could manually run the middleware:

```
def test_getBaz(self):
    request = HttpRequest('/blarg')
    request.session['foo'] = 2

    middleware = FooMiddleware()
    request = middleware.process_request(request)

    value = getBaz(request)
    assertEqual( value, expected )
```

but that seems like a hack. What if the middleware under test depends on another middleware?

### < /Possibility >

Answer (score 3):

I've seen your "manual" solution, but I suggest you consider using the test client described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#testing-tools

As to the middleware dependency, you might consider mocking that middleware.

Comment: I think that's insufficient. Using the django client gives me a response. but what do I do with it? there's nothing I want to do with the response. Rather, I have a method attaching itself to the _request_. By the time the django Client hands me the _response_, I no longer have access to the request (which has a method attached to it from the middleware).

Comment: The response returned by the test client does have access to the request. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Response.request

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (I can't test this idea right now, but I'm having the same problem as you have): would it be a solution to inlude a context processor that takes simply returns the request variables inserted by the middleware component?

Comment: I've just tried this out, and it works fine indeed. It doesn't _feel_ right, but it'll do for me for now.